# Renew iOS Development and APNs Production for Corporate Apps [AirWatch]

Tags: ios7, mdm, ios-provisioning, airwatch

I have developed an iOS app for my corporation. We distribute it via AirWatch. Some of the certs are going to expire soon and it is SO confusing to try to figure out what to do. I have googled and it seems every page has different information. I would really love it if someone could point me in the correct direction.

1. I have an "iOS Development" cert with my name on it. It appears that I cannot renew it, only revoke or download. Some pages said if I download it again it gets updated, some say I need to create a new cert. Which one is it, and do I do this in Xcode or on the portal?
2. I have an "APNs Production iOS" cert with my company's id on it(the reverse dns thing, like "com.apple.mobile". It is also due soon. How do I renew, and where do I renew it, in Xcode or the portal.

We do not use Apple Push Notifications in the app, but I am under the impression that you still need this as it is the way Apple securely identifies your app. Is this true?

1. I have a "iOS Provisioning Profile" that will also expire. Same questions. Can I just edit it to renew it? Do I do this in Xcode or Portal.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Was the below answer satisfactory? I know this is 9 months old but it would be beneficial to the community to be thorough.

Comment: Yes, it was. Thank you for reminding me. I have upvoted the answer and marked it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to renew your profiles (all that you are using for development or distribution.  Then, you will need to re-build any apps that were built with the old profiles.  Otherwise, no one will be able to install the app that was build with the expired profile.  Basically, any apps built and distributed with an enterprise distribution profile will need to be re-built at least once a year.

**Edit:** more details on how to generate a new certificate.

Just go the the ios developer portal, and go to the area on the right for Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles on the right.  Go to the Certificates area, and click the + icon to generate a new certificate.  Follow the instructions there for generating the new cert.  Once you have your new cert, go to the profiles section, and you will need to re-generate your profiles with the new cert.  For each profile, click the edit button, change the certificate dropdown to your new certificate, and then click the Generate button.  Download the new profile, and use it to re-build your apps.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Are there any good links for how to do this? I have googled this question and I am seeing very different answers.